# C++ 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am trying to run the below C++ code and I get this error :
Could anyone please help me clarify why is this the issue
Input : input/text_4.txt 9

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
After reading a few similar threads, the solution is to check dynamic memory allocation. However, my code does not have any dynamically allocated memory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;
vector<string> arrangefile(vector<string>& scale, int width, int &number) {
        int beginning = 0; int total = 0;
        vector<string> result;
        for(int i = 0; i < scale.size(); i++)
        {
            total += scale[i].size(); // add length of each word 

            if(total + i - beginning > width) // checking if the value has exceeded the maximum width 
            {
                total -= scale[i].size(); 
                string sentence= "",low="";
                int last = i-1;
                int space = width - total; // calculate number of spaces in each line
                int check = max(last-beginning, 1); 
                int even = space/check;
                while(even--){
                    low += " ";
                }
                int mod = space%check;
                for(int j = beginning; j <= last; j++)
                {
                    sentence += scale[j]; //find all values in a sentence
                    if(j < last || beginning == last) 
                        sentence += low; // add the word low to the larger sentence
                    if(j - beginning < mod) 
                        sentence += " ";                    
                }
                result.push_back(sentence); // add the sentence to the vector
                number++; // counts the number of sentences
                beginning = i;
                total = scale[i].size();
            }
        }
        
        string sentence =""; // for the last line
        int last = scale.size()-1;
        int check = last-beginning;
        int space = width - total - check;
        string low="";
        while(space--){
            low += " ";
        }
        for(int j = beginning; j <= last; j++)
        {
            sentence += scale[j];
            if(j < last){
                sentence += " "; 
            }               
        }
        sentence += low;
        result.push_back(sentence); // // add the sentence to the vector
        number++; // counts the number of sentences
        return result;
    }

int main(){
    string filepath, word;
    int M, number=0;
    cin >> filepath;
    cin >> M;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filepath.c_str());
    unsigned found = filepath.find_last_of("/");
    string b = filepath.substr(found+1);
    int create = b.size();
    string between = b.substr(0, create-4);
    string final = between + "_formatted.txt";
    string ending = "output/" + final;
    mkdir ("output", 0777);
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(ending);
    for(int i = 0, count = 0; i<M; i++, count ++){
        if(count == 9){
            fout<<count;
            count = -1;
        }
        else
            fout<<count;
    }
    fout<<endl;
    vector <string> first;
    vector <string> second;
    while(fin >> word){
        first.push_back(word);
    }
    if(first.empty()){
        cout<<"0 formatted lines written to "<< ending<<endl;
    }
    else{
        second = arrangefile(first, M,number);
        for (auto i = second.begin(); i != second.end(); ++i) 
            fout << *i <<endl;
        cout<<number<<" formatted lines written to "<<ending<<endl;
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

input file text_4.txt:

This is because not very many happy things happened
in the lives of the three Baudelaire youngsters.

Input: input/text_4.txt 8

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Comment: You use `std::vector`. It's a "dynamic array" which allocates and reallocates dynamically as needed.

Comment: How am I supposed to solve this issue ?

Comment: The first comment told you how. That is the first thing a programmer should do in the situation. Use a debugger to figure out the source of the problem.

Comment: You have `unsigned found = filepath.find_last_of("/")` and then `filepath.substr(found + 1)` *without* checking the value of `found`.  What if `filepath` doesn't contain a '/' character?

Comment: @G.M.. It always has ''/"

Comment: One possible cause is if one of your accesses to the `scale` vector is out of bounds.  Using `at()` instead of `operator[]` would help you catch that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude am I supposed to delete the vector ?

Comment: ***am I supposed to delete the vector ?*** No.

Comment: Note that I am just guessing; without your input file I can't run your code to attempt to reproduce the problem.  So if you want more specific help, post an input file that triggers the crash.  On a similar note, it'd be courteous to post the *complete* source code, including the `#include` lines, so that a person can compile and run your code verbatim without having to tweak it.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have updated my post and included the header files and the input :) Sorry about not including it earlier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I run your code, on the `i==16` iteration of the outer loop in `arrangefile`, we get `width==8` and `total==10`, with `check==1`.  As a result, `even` is initialized to  `-2`, and so the `while(even--)` loop is (nearly) infinite.  So it attempts to add spaces to `low` until it runs out of memory.

(Note that the memory used by `std::string` is dynamically allocated, so your code *does* have dynamic memory allocation.  The same for `std::vector`.)

I haven't analyzed your algorithm closely enough to figure out the correct fix, but it's possible your loop should be `while(even-- > 0)` instead.

---

I'll second the tip in the comments to use your debugger, and I'll repost the link: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058).  That's how I found this bug.

I ran the program under the debugger `gdb`.  It ran for a few seconds, at which point I got suspicious because the program doesn't appear do anything complicated enough to take that much computation time.  So I interrupted the program (Ctrl-C) which let me see where it was and what it was doing.  I could see that it was within the `while(even--)` loop.  That was also suspicious because that loop should complete very fast.  So I inspected the value of `even` (with the command `p even`) and saw that it was a large negative number.  That could only happen if it had started as a negative number, which logically could only happen if `total` were greater than `width`.  Inspecting their values I could see that this was indeed the case.

Maybe this will be helpful as you learn more about using your debugger.